# What units, if any, were removed or restricted from Heart of the Swarm multiplayer

Tags: starcraft-2

During development of Heart of the Swarm, there were several mentions (e.g. the [Thor](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=278842), [Carrier, and Mothership](http://www.gosugamers.net/starcraft2/news/17439-blizzcon-from-the-floor-mothership-carrier-removed-in-hots)) of units being removed (or restricted to 1) in HOTS multiplayer (compared to Wings of Liberty multiplayer).

In the final release of the expansion, what units have been removed from Heart of the Swarm multiplayer?

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106193/what-balance-changes-were-made-between-the-final-wings-of-liberty-patch-and-hear :)